# Use Python C-API to get the current size of value stack

Tags: python, c, python-c-api

I'm playing with Python's C-API. Specifically, I want to see if I can inspect how many elements the value stack currently has. Here's my code:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <frameobject.h>

int test() {
    PyFrameObject* f = PyEval_GetFrame();
    return (int)(f->f_stacktop - f->f_valuestack);
}
```

I'm not sure whether this can work, but this line exists in [Python's source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Objects/frameobject.c#L314), so I gave it a try.

This usually results in negative number, something like `-547715639`.

So clearly I'm doing it wrong, probably because what'e described in the documentation: ["Frame evaluation usually NULLs it (f_stacktop)"](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Include/frameobject.h#L25). What's the right way to do it, or is it even possible?

Comment: Can you provide some context for your use-case? Is it one-off? dev-time? production? profiling? debugging? etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44443331/2142577).

In short, I should use

```c
(int)(stack_pointer - f->f_valuestack);
```

However, `stack_pointer` is a local varaible inside the [_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Python/ceval.c#L1076) function, thus can't be accessed from outside.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is impossible ‍♀️

Here's how I get things from value stack in a compiled extension module:

```c
    PyObject **stack_pointer = frame->f_stacktop;

    if (frame->f_stacktop == frame->f_valuestack) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, "stack is empty");
        return NULL;
    }

    if (!stack_pointer) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, "stack pointer is null?");
        return NULL;
    }

    // Top-most on the value stack ought to be the "receiver".
    PyObject *next = stack_pointer[-1];
```

Source: https://github.com/dimaqq/awaitwhat/blob/e242ea7502cd13ebf7aca16700240aa592467f3a/awaitwhat/what.c#L24-L37

And here's how to get it in Python using `ctypes`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14034945/705086

Comment: Sorry, I didn't really get it. How do you get the size of value stack?

Comment: The delta between stack top and value stack (in elements) is the number of values on the stack. Caveats: stack grows downwards, thus, first element is at `[-1]`; I think one of these values is not updated after every instruction (that's an optimisation), but it is updated when e.g. generator is suspended, probably if this frame calls a function, etc.

Comment: This answer(https://stackoverflow.com/a/44443331/2142577) explains why most of the time `f_stacktop` is null, so I don't think this is a general solution. Your lib is targeting `aysnc/await` scenarios, which, `f_stacktop` happens to not be NULL.

Comment: This make sense, while Python executes classical synchronous code, 1 eval frame ≅ 1 python frame, thus stack top is only kept on (C) stack. Generators and coroutines break this equality, so stack top must be persisted. If it's the earlier, then read it like `gdb` would. On Linux, you can do this at runtime with `bpftrace` or `oprofile`, batteries not included :) If your use-case is a one-off, build custom cpython with a few tweaks :)

Comment: Yes. But anyway, I found a way that does not require knowing the stack size, so it's fine. It's for debugging purposes.